# How can I add delete buttons to clear whole state and remove specific state that .map function turns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router

I tried to initial the array to remove all elements at inside of it but it did not work.

```
clearAll(){
   this.setState({
      posts: []
   })
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(Response => {
        console.log(Response)
        this.setState({posts:Response.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.setState({errorMsg: "Error retreiving data !"})
        })
    }

render() {
    const {posts , errorMsg} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            Post List Here.
            {
                posts.length ?
                posts.map(post => <div> key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>) :
                null
            }
            { errorMsg ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I checked shopping carts and watched videos about that to find button that removes specific state but it did not work again. Can someone give me a button or idea about that? I need 2 buttons for removing all state that are coming from .json and removing specific one of them.

Comment: You never call the clearAll function. Probably a binding issue: `onClick={()=>this.clearAll()}` should fix that

Comment: Do you mean removing a specific post and and one for removing all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your `clearAll` function to delete all posts,

```
clearAll(){
   this.setState({
      posts: []
   })
}

removePost(postId){
  this.setState(state=>({posts: state.posts.filter(post=> post.id !== postId)})
}
```

to remove specific post. Call inside `post` `<div/>` button `onClick`

```
render() {
const {posts , errorMsg} = this.state
return (
    <div>
        Post List Here.
        {
            posts.length ?
            posts.map(post => <div key={post.id}><div>{post.title}</div><button type="button" onClick={()=>this.removePost(post.id)}>Remove Post</button></div>) :
            null
        }
        { errorMsg ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : null}
        <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.clearAll()}>Remove All Posts</button>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but can I ask something little? When I execute the project, it says "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." but we already gave them keys. why it happens?

Comment: @Pensar Nada , oh sorry i missed out on something, just move your `key` prop from the inner `<div/>` to the outer `<div/>`

Comment: Thank you so much again, I'm working on this for many days and I just realised that I'm right around of the solution :D

Answer (score 1):

create the

```
 const initatialState={
posts:[],
errorMsg:''
}
when you want cleat ued 
clearAll=()=>{
this.setState({...initatialState})}
```

tell me if it work in commit